# Programa exibe um valor aleatório

Tags: c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

```
float notas[6]={100,50,20,10,5,2};
float moedas[6]={1.00,0.50,0.25,0.10,0.05,0.01};
float resto,resto2;
float N;
scanf("%f", &N);
printf("NOTAS:\n");
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    int qnt=N/notas[i];
    resto= fmodf(N,notas[i]);
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %.2f\n", qnt,notas[i]);
    N=resto;
}

printf("MOEDAS:\n");
for(int c=0;c<7;c++){
    int qnt2=N/moedas[c];
    resto2= fmodf(N,moedas[c]);
    printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ %.2f\n", qnt2,moedas[c]);
    N=resto2;
}
return 0;
```

}*

Entrada:576,73

A saída esta sendo: NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
**-2147483648 nota(s) de R$ 0.00**
MOEDAS:
0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
**0 moeda(s) de R$ 100.00**

Answer (score 0):

Os loops no seu código tem uma posição a mais... E note que no enunciado o texto aparece em maiúsculas. Você pode evitar esses números mágicos no programa e deixar a conta genérica, e copiar o texto quando é algo chato como esses problemas corrigidos automaticamente.

Veja esse exemplo, onde a função `entrega()` tem umas 15 linhas mostra a mensagem esperada (ao final tem um exemplo interativo como o que o site espera):

O programa roda com os exemplos que tem lá no enunciado mais os casos limite que estão lá, 0 e 1 milhão, mais a primeira nota e a última moeda. As mensagens foram copiadas direto do site assim deve mesmo ficar igualzinho :) Fica faltando só preencher o número de cada nota ou moeda:

```
        printf(linha[1 + j], notas);
```

E para evitar *stress* com o arredondamento depois de contar as notas de 100 o programa faz o simples: converte o saldo para `int`.

#### Veja o código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void entrega(double); // entrega o valor

int main(void)
{
    double valor_teste[] =
    {
        0.,
        1000000.,
        576.73,  // ex 1
        4., // 2
        91.01, // 3
        100.,
        0.01
    };

    int N = sizeof(valor_teste) / sizeof(valor_teste[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        entrega(valor_teste[i]);
    return 0;
}

void entrega(double valor)
{
    const char* linha[] = {"%d notas (s) de R$ 100.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 50.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 20.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 10.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 5.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 2.00\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 1.00\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.50\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.25\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.10\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.05\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.01\n"};
    int pt[] =
    {
        5000, 2000,  1000,
         500,  200,   100,
          50,   25,    10,
           5,    1
    };

    int notas = 0;
    printf("\n==> %.2f\n\nNOTAS:\n", valor);
    while (valor >= 100.) notas += 1, valor -= 100.;
    printf(linha[0], notas);
    notas = 0;
    int saldo = (int)(valor*100.); // converte para int
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 1)
    {  // sem arredondamento
        notas = 0;
        while (saldo >= pt[j]) notas += 1, saldo -= pt[j];
        if (j == 5) printf("MOEDAS:\n");
        printf(linha[1 + j], notas);
    };  // for()
    return;
}
```

Saida do programa

```
==> 0.00

NOTAS:
0 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 1000000.00

NOTAS:
10000 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 576.73

NOTAS:
5 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
1 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
1 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
1 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
3 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 4.00

NOTAS:
0 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
2 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 91.01

NOTAS:
0 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
1 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
2 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
1 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 100.00

NOTAS:
1 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01

==> 0.01

NOTAS:
0 notas (s) de R$ 100.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 50.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 20.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 10.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 5.00
0 notas (s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda (s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda (s) de R$ 0.05
1 moeda (s) de R$ 0.01
```

### Um programa interativo como o exemplo do Beecrowd

É a função do exemplo acima:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char* linha[] = {"%d notas (s) de R$ 100.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 50.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 20.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 10.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 5.00\n",
                           "%d notas (s) de R$ 2.00\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 1.00\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.50\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.25\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.10\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.05\n",
                           "%d moeda (s) de R$ 0.01\n"};
    int         pt[]    = {5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100,
                           50,   25,   10,   5,   1};
    double valor = 0.;
    int res = scanf("%lf", &valor);
    if (res != 1) return -1;
    int notas = 0;
    printf("\n==> %.2f\n\nNOTAS:\n", valor);
    while (valor >= 100.) notas += 1, valor -= 100.;
    printf(linha[0], notas);
    notas     = 0;
    int saldo = (int)(valor * 100.);  // converte para int
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 1)
    {  // sem arredondamento
        notas = 0;
        while (saldo >= pt[j]) notas += 1, saldo -= pt[j];
        if (j == 5) printf("MOEDAS:\n");
        printf(linha[1 + j], notas);
    };  // for()
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu ainda tô tentando entender o seu código. Mas aparentemente ele ta rodando tudo certo, como ainda sou inicianteestou com dificuldade de entender sua lógica

Comment: Não há muito de lógica nisso que eu fiz: é como se fosse um formulário e já tem o texto com os valores. Tudo copiado do enunciado . O programa só preenche a janelinha dos números de todas as notas e moedas. A única "lógica" a considerar é que tudo acima de 100 reais vai ser pago em notas de 100 e então é deduzido antes. Depois sobra no máximo `99.99` e é mais tranquilo multiplicar tudo por 100 e converter para inteiro porque não há mais possível arredondamento...

Answer (score -2):

Tenta este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float notas[6]={100.00,50.00,20.00,10.00,5.00,2.00};
    float moedas[6]={1.00,0.50,0.25,0.10,0.05,0.01};
    float resto;
    float N;
    int qnt;
    scanf("%f", &N);
    N = N + 0.001; // adiocanar esse pequeno 'ruido'
    system("cls"); //limpa a tela
    printf("NOTAS:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
      qnt = (int) (N / notas[i]);
      resto = fmodf(N,notas[i]);
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %f\n", qnt, notas[i]);
      N = resto;
    }
    printf("MOEDAS:\n");
    for(int c=0;c<6;c++){
      qnt = (int) (N / moedas[c]);
      resto =  fmodf(N,moedas[c]);
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ %f\n", qnt, moedas[c]);
      N = resto;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Se funcionar me avisa.

Answer (score -3):

Seu problema é que você está rodando o loop até 7 posições, quanto seu vetor só tem 6, lembre que o C indenta os vetores a partir do 0, então você está lendo uma volta a mais, nessa o resto fica recebe um valor nulo, que é passado para o N e atrapalha a divisão das moedas, diminua seu laço para **i<6**.

Comment: Eu percebi isso agora pouco: corrigi. Agora o programa roda todas as respostas corretas. porém, continua dando Wrong Answer 100%. Nao to entendendo o pq.

Comment: Vi aqui o erro, acho que você está usando um programa de correção, não é?, Ele deve checar a saída exata, mas existe vários jeitos de ver a saída, talvez seja isso, mas algumas vezes seu programa arredonda o resultado da divisao

Comment: Sim, é o desafio 1021 da Beecrowd. Todas as saídas testes estão batendo agora nesse novo código. Mas mesmo assim ele não aceita.